# How to pass any action from one application running in PC1 to different application running in PC2

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, action

One application is just filewatcher which runs all the time in the background.. And it updates the database when any new files are added. This application updates only two field of the database. Primary key **part** and the ** attachment. **
Again, I have a different  **main application**  which is handled by a different user in different PC. So this application has a **Transfer button** to move when any new files are updated in the database. This button’s action causes the file to move from cell[2] to cell[3]. Which means it moves all the files from location C:\user\fab to location: C:\user\release. This application doesn’t have any file watcher

So my issue is:

The file watcher is updating perfectly everything to the database. But when the other user is moving the files with the help of a single ** Transfer button press**. The file watcher which is running on a different PC thinks that the file got deleted and its taking the command to delete the database. Any solution for this. Please help me out.

Links first part: https://imageshack.com/i/idZuIKPnj

Second part : https://imageshack.com/i/idJzeEtwj

Code snippet:

```
    private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {

        switch (e.ChangeType)
        {
            case WatcherChangeTypes.Created:
                //Insert file in database
                this.Invoke(addItemInList, "File: " + e.FullPath + " Created");
                {
                    string filename = Path.GetFileName(e.FullPath);
                    filename = filename.Substring(0, filename.LastIndexOf("."));
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DVSQL\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CncDB;User ID=CncDbUser;password=gcodedata");
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO cncinfo (part,draftpath) VALUES ('" + filename + "','" + e.FullPath + "') ", con);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
                break;
            case WatcherChangeTypes.Deleted:
                //remove file from database
                this.Invoke(addItemInList, "File: " + e.FullPath + " Deleted");
                {
                    string filename = Path.GetFileName(e.FullPath);
                    filename = filename.Substring(0, filename.LastIndexOf("."));
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DVSQL\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CncDB;User ID=CncDbUser;password=gcodedata");
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"delete cncinfo where part='" + filename + "'  ;", con);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
                break;
            case WatcherChangeTypes.Changed:
                ///if you are storing file in database(not file name whole file in binary format)
                ///then you can update the file in database here
                ///this event will be fired when any data has changed in the file.
                this.Invoke(addItemInList, "File: " + e.FullPath + " Changed");
                {
                    string filename = Path.GetFileName(e.FullPath);
                    filename = filename.Substring(0, filename.LastIndexOf("."));
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DVSQL\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CncDB;User ID=CncDbUser;password=gcodedata");
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"update cncinfo set part='" + filename
                        + "',draftpath='" + e.FullPath + "' where part='" + filename + "'", con);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    this.Validate();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Update then old filename with new here
        this.Invoke(addItemInList, string.Format("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath));
        {
            //string extension = e.FullPath.Substring(e.FullPath.LastIndexOf("."));
            string oldFileName = Path.GetFileName(e.OldFullPath);
            oldFileName = oldFileName.Substring(0, oldFileName.LastIndexOf("."));
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(e.FullPath);
            filename = filename.Substring(0, filename.LastIndexOf("."));
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DVSQL\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CncDB;User ID=CncDbUser;password=gcodedata");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"update cncinfo set part='" + filename + "',draftpath='" + e.FullPath + "' where part='" + oldFileName + "'", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            this.Validate();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also declare another filewatcher for destination folder where you move the files. But, As i have told u you ASP.NET room you have to make a signature of that particular file (ie. with the combination of file size, Modified Date and FileType) You can make a class like `FileSignature`

```
public class FileSignature
{
    public int FileSize { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; } //We could not take CreatedDate because it will be changed once the file moved but, modified date only change when it modified by editor (ie. notepad)
    public String FileType { get; set; }

    public String OldFileName { get; set; } //this is not the part of the combination of signature. It is just to get the old file name which is moved from.
}
```

and create the object of that class into a list when Delete file event occured.

```
private List<FileSignature> movedList = new List<FileSignature>();
private void Watcher1_OnChange()
{
    ....
    case Delete:
        FileSignature singature = new FileSignature();
        FileInfo info = new System.IO.FileInfo(e.FullPath);
        signature.FileSize = info.Length;
        signature.ModifiedDate = info.LastWriteTime;
        singature.FileType = info.Extension;
        signature.OldFileName = e.FullPath;
        movedList.Add(signature);
        break;

}
```

[FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class will contains all the information about the file.

Now, you need another `FileWatcher` object for destination folder path (ie. C:\user\release).

in the second file watcher `OnChanged` event you will get the event which file has been created and moved from another location.

```
private void Watcher2_OnChange()
{
    ....
    case Created:
        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
        FileSignature[] found = (from FileSignature sign in movedList 
                          where sign.ModifiedDate == info.LastWriteTime &&
                                sign.FileType == info.Extension &&
                                sign.FileSize == info.Length
                         select sign).ToArray()
        if (found.Length > 0)  //if the file found then it will be known as moved file otherwise created.
        {
            FileSignature signature = found[0]; //we will take only one file from the index 0. coz the file watcher event will occur for every file separately.
            //remove that file from the list first. So, further undeleted item in the list will be known as deleted at the end.
            movedList.Remove(signature);

            string oldFileName = signature.OldFileName; //this will contain full path of file which has been moved to new location.
            string newFileName = e.FullPath; //this will return new file name which is moved from source directory
            //Now you can perform you database update process here for move file. 
            //you have both path and flag that file is moved.
        } 
        else
        {
            //Now you can perform you database update process here for create file. 
        }

        break;    
}
```

**Now, the main part of the code is here**

now You need a flag that will be updated from your main application when the whole process completed(file moving). You can use another `FileWatcher` for it.

When you get the flag that process has been dene from a Main Application then you can call the another method to delete the items from the database which are exist in `movedList`.

```
private void DeleteItems()
{
     foreach (FileSignature signature in movedList)
    {
         string filename = signature.OldFileName
         //Delete from the database. coz this files are known as deleted but not moved to destination 
    }
}
```

Comment: i know your answer will be the best shot.. i dont even need to run this code.. It will the perfect of anything!!! Thanks a lot for generating valuable code for me. !!!!!! :P

Answer (score 0):

Well your file watcher only has 3 actions.  Does your file watcher load history of the folder somehow?  In other words if your file watcher does not keep historical data, you could kill the Filewatcher.exe, move the file, and then re-enable.  The problem with that approach is you might miss a change or creation in the folder while the exe is off.

The second solution is to copy the file and rename the original file appending "FILEMOVED202" or any unique string to the end of the file name, so that Test.doc would be TestFILEMOVED202.doc and would fire the change function in your file watcher.  In your changed function you can then string function the file name for the string.  If it exists in the change function then delete the actual file from the file watcher, supress the delete logging with another flag, and update the database with the value moved or whatever.

The only thing you have ready access to in the file watcher would be the file name, not file contents, so I would use that as your flag vehicle.

Comment: i dint get your second solution

Comment: Go to the second Application that has the "Transfer" Button press.  Make that code copy the file to the transfer destination, not move it so the delete function never fires.  AFTER the file copies rename the original file adding any unique string to the file name.  Like Test.docx would become TestFileMovedTrans.doc.  That would then fire the change event of you file watcher, it drops into the change code above.  In that change code check the file name for your unique string "FileMovedTrans" or whatever.  If it has that string the move function caused it & you can log and delete the file

Answer (score 0):

Go to the second Application that has the "Transfer" Button press. Make that code copy the file to the transfer destination, not move it so the delete function never fires. AFTER the file copies rename the original file adding any unique string to the file name. Like Test.docx would become TestFileMovedTrans.doc. That would then fire the change event of you file watcher, it drops into the change code above. In that change code check the file name for your unique string "FileMovedTrans" or whatever. If it has that string the move function caused it & you can log and delete the file

Once you delete the file in your Change code that is going to fire the Filewatcher Delete code again where you would check for the string in the file name a second time.  If the string exists do not log it to the database as deleted since it was merely moved, and if the string is not in the file name just use your regular Delete functionality.